# Rails 5, Carrierwave. Could not find generator 'uploader'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have installed Carrierwave successfully. I can see it from the terminal: `gem list carrierwave` =>

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

carrierwave (1.0.0.rc)
```

But I still can not generate uploader...  If I run `rails g uploader Picture` in terminal I get `Could not find generator 'uploader'`.

My only thought is that there might be some conflicts between gems. Here is the gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', '6.4.0.3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.11.2'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-google'
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was quite silly. Before using Carrierwave I have duplicated my app folders directory by hand (you know, that right click and copy/paste :D) but terminal was using the old one... Even though I thought I switched to the new one...

Answer (score 11):

Issue might be of spring cache. Write following command and try again

```
  bin/spring stop
```

thats it :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the stable version of the gem. 
Switch to 0.11.2

**Update**:

And install the gem manually too.
`gem install carrierwave'

=> https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/219

Comment: I have tried all kind of versions. And changing to this version doesent work either. I deleted gem, changed it in gem file to 0.11.2 version, ran bundle install and still - couldnt find uploader...

Comment: It won't help unless you update the Gemfile, also.  Even if 0.11.2 is installed, it'll pull the newer version.  Make sure to specify something like `gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.11'` in your Gemfile.  You can ignore the linked issue as it's 5+ years old at this point.  I've never had that issue and I use CarrierWave extensively.

Comment: ok, so I have uninstalled carrierwave. No other versions were installed (checked that by `gem carrierwave list`). Included gem `'carrierwave', '~> 0.11.2'` into the gemfile, ran `bundle install` and still couldnt find uploader...

Comment: Please delete your Gemfile.lock too while delete gem.

Comment: Thanks for help, I appreciate!